# Access attribute of elements within numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array full of objects (dtype=object) of the `cftime` class.

```
In [1]: a
Out[1]: 
array([cftime.DatetimeNoLeap(2000, 1, 1, 11, 29, 59, 999996, 5, 1),
       cftime.DatetimeNoLeap(2000, 1, 2, 11, 29, 59, 999996, 6, 2),
       cftime.DatetimeNoLeap(2000, 1, 3, 11, 29, 59, 999996, 0, 3)],
      dtype=object)

In [2]: type(a[0])
Out[2]: cftime._cftime.DatetimeNoLeap
```

Each of these objects has an attribute `month`.

```
a[0].month
Out[66]: 1
```

I'd like to get a new numpy array with the same shape, but filled with this attribute for each of the elements of the original array. Something like `b=a.month`. But obviously this fails, as `a` is a numpy array without `month` attribute. How can I achieve this result?

PS: of course I could do this with a plain Python loop, but I'd like to follow a fully numpy approach:

```
b=np.zeros_like(a, dtype=int)
for i in range(a.size):
    b[i] = a[i].month
```

Comment: Not a numpy answer but short of that you should use a loop/list comprehension. You can create a list by saying `list = [ele] * n` , but the elements all reference the same memory space - modifying any of them will affect the others. Loop/list comprehension avoids this.

Comment: Why the object array instead of a list? It's not any faster or easier.

Comment: Not my choice. This is how I get the data from a preliminary call to the `num2date` function of the the cftime package.

Comment: `cftime` is written in `cython` (Python compiled to `c` (as much as possible)).  So make sure you use its own functionality as much as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.2/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html), in order to map a function to every element in the array. For this case you can define a custom `lambda` function to extract the month of each entry `lambda x: x.month`:

```
np.vectorize(lambda x: x.month)(a)
array([1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: Using `np.frompyfunc` might be faster.  `vectorize` uses it, but tends to be slower.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, will give it a look :-)

Comment: Did it help @Onturenio ? Don't forget to upvote/accept the answer if it did, thanks!

Comment: I tried it and it worked, but I also read about the fact that `vectorize` is pretty much a wrapper for a loop, so not really a numpy-performance approach. But I acknowledge that your solution works, so I'll accept it as solved. Still, I'll try to research other options that might be faster, perhaps the `frompyfunc` is the way to proceed.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I do not think this can be vectorized, after all `numpy` is not really a tool to work with `datetime` objects or similar. So you'll have to use something similar to a `map` in standart python, and in numpy you can either use `vectorize` or `frompyfunc` as @hpaulj suggestes

Comment: An object array contains pointers to objects elsewhere in memory.  That's similar to a `list`.  Access to the attributes of those objects requires the same kind of Python methods.  `frompyfunc` streamlines the iteration through those pointers as much as possible, but there's still a lot of Python level processing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have `cftime` installed, so will demonstrate with regular datetime objects.

First make an array of datetime objects - the lazy way using numpy's own datetime dtype:

```
In [599]: arr = np.arange('2000-01-11','2000-12-31',dtype='datetime64[D]')
In [600]: arr.shape
Out[600]: (355,)
```

Make an object dtype array from that:

```
In [601]: arrO = arr.astype(object)
```

and a list of datetimes as well:

```
In [602]: alist = arr.tolist()
```

Timing for regular list comprehension:

```
In [603]: timeit [d.month for d in alist]
20.1 µs ± 62.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

List comprehension on a object dtype array is usually a bit slower (but faster than a list comprehension on a regular array):

```
In [604]: timeit [d.month for d in arrO]
30.7 µs ± 266 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

`frompyfunc` - here it's slower; other times I've see it 2x faster than a list comprehension:

```
In [605]: timeit np.frompyfunc(lambda x: x.month, 1,1)(arrO)
51 µs ± 32.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

`vectorize` is (nearly) always slower than `frompyfunc` (even though it uses `frompyfunc` for the actual iteration):

```
In [606]: timeit np.vectorize(lambda x: x.month, otypes=[int])(arrO)
76.7 µs ± 123 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Here are samples of the arrays and list:

```
In [607]: arr[:5]
Out[607]: 
array(['2000-01-11', '2000-01-12', '2000-01-13', '2000-01-14',
       '2000-01-15'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
In [608]: arrO[:5]
Out[608]: 
array([datetime.date(2000, 1, 11), datetime.date(2000, 1, 12),
       datetime.date(2000, 1, 13), datetime.date(2000, 1, 14),
       datetime.date(2000, 1, 15)], dtype=object)
In [609]: alist[:5]
Out[609]: 
[datetime.date(2000, 1, 11),
 datetime.date(2000, 1, 12),
 datetime.date(2000, 1, 13),
 datetime.date(2000, 1, 14),
 datetime.date(2000, 1, 15)]
```

`frompyfunc` and `vectorize` are best used when you want the generality of broadcasting and multidimensional arrays.  For 1d arrays, a list comprehension is nearly always better.

To fairer to `frompyfunc`, I should return an array from the list comprehension:

```
In [610]: timeit np.array([d.month for d in arrO])
50.1 µs ± 36.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

To get the best speed with dates in numpy, use the `datatime64` dtype instead of object dtype.  This makes more use of compiled numpy code.

```
In [611]: timeit arr = np.arange('2000-01-11','2000-12-31',dtype='datetime64[D]'
     ...: )
3.16 µs ± 51 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [616]: arr.astype('datetime64[M]')[::60]
Out[616]: 
array(['2000-01', '2000-03', '2000-05', '2000-07', '2000-09', '2000-11'],
      dtype='datetime64[M]')
```

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. Just what I needed as I am dealing with datetime64.