# Construct a class that allows calling methods through numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I define a class `Tomato` and create an array with several objects of that class:

```
import numpy as np
class Tomato:
    color = None
    radius = None
    def __init__(self):
        color = np.random.choice(['red', 'green'])
        radius = np.random.rand()

arr1 = np.array([Tomato() for i in range(6)]).reshape(3, 2)
arr1
```

yields

```
array([[<__main__.Tomato object at 0x000002479E7D97F0>,
        <__main__.Tomato object at 0x000002479E7D9710>],
       [<__main__.Tomato object at 0x000002479E7D94E0>,
        <__main__.Tomato object at 0x000002479E7D9DA0>],
       [<__main__.Tomato object at 0x000002479E710630>,
        <__main__.Tomato object at 0x000002479E7D9C18>]], dtype=object)
```

I would like to be able to call

```
arr1.radius
```

and get a 3x2 array containing just the `radius` of each tomato. I know I can use `np.vectorize()` or a lambda expression, as recommended in questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54199914/access-attribute-of-elements-within-numpy-array) where the asker was working with objects from an externally imported `cftime` class.

But I believe I should have more options since I defined the `Tomato` class myself.

For example, the `complex128` data type has the methods `.real` and `.imag`, and so does an array of complex floats.

```
arr2 = np.random.normal(size=(3, 2)) + 1j * np.random.normal(size=(3, 2))
arr2.imag
```

gives you the imaginary part of each entry:

```
array([[-0.23054982,  0.04599812],
       [-0.07459619, -0.11282513],
       [-0.32441139,  0.8920348 ]])
```

**Is there a way to modify `Tomato`'s class definition to allow users to access its attributes through a numpy array?**

If not, how does the `arr2` example above work? Are the `.real` and `.imag` methods specified manually in the code for the numpy array class?

Comment: `numpy` is not designed to work with python objects. At least, not efficiently. 
 `complex128` is just a wrapper type, the primitive numeric type that numpy arrays actually contain aren't actually Python objects. At that point, you *might as well just use regular lists*. In this case you may actually want to use a structured array, which allows you to work with numpy arrays of primitive structs, where you can write numpy code in terms of the struct's fields.

Comment: Taking a step back, *why* are you using `numpy` here?

Comment: Note, *all* numpy.ndarray objects have a `imag` and `real` attributes. That isn't due to the `dtype=complex128`.

Comment: The actual thing I'm developing is a sort of particle simulator. I have a particle class with position and velocity attributes. I put the particles in an array, and then I would like to use some of the convenient vectorized methods built into numpy (like `np.linalg.norm`) to perform calculations that depend on these attributes, and then update the attributes themselves based on the results of the calculations. But I am also new to the idea of object-oriented programming in general, and just trying to get a feel for what's possible and what's reasonable.

Comment: Similar question earlier today https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62903596/python-get-array-of-the-variables-same-variable-from-an-array-of-classes.  The fast `numpy` code is compiled, using `c` numeric types.  Your `arr1` contains references to objects stored elsewhere in memory.  `numpy` does not a mechanism for reaching into your Python code and treat it in a compiled manner.

Comment: @Max Numpy **is not designed** to work with Python objects. Most of those numeric methods won't begin to work with any custom python type, and I don't even think they work with structured numpy dtypes.  most of the efficient numpy linear algebra routines are calling some BLAS / LAPACK library on the backend, which require primitive numeric dtypes (they are essentially hand-tuned, fortran/c/assembler routines that work on primitive numeric arrays, that is where their speed comes from). You are going about this fundamentally the wrong way, if you want to use numpy as your main tool

Comment: @Max: if you make a particle simulation, you should represent the particle as a tuple of numbers, and thus not wrap it in a class, but simply see it as a row, etc. of a numpy array. Numpy will wrap values in a class if you retrieve these, but behind the curtains, it works mostly on unboxed arrays.

Comment: @Max your class definition has bugs. An obvious one is that `self` is missing in the `__init__` statements. A more subtle one is that you initialize `color` and `radius` as class attributes, which you should only do if either they won't change or if it is a mutable object that needs to be shared between class instances. In this case, it works because you initialize them as immutable `None`. but you'll get surprises if you use mutable datatypes such as lists or arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own class for the use cases that you provide (i.e., slicing and initialization):

```
import numpy as np
class TomatoArr:
    def __init__(self, col, r):
        self.col = col if isinstance(col, np.ndarray) else np.array(col, dtype='<U5')
        self.r = r if isinstance(r, np.ndarray) else np.array(r, dtype=float)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return TomatoArr(self.col[idx], self.r[idx])
   
    @classmethod
    def from_list(cls, tlist):
        n = len(tlist)
        col = np.array([a.col for a in tlist], dtype='<U5')
        r = np.array([a.r for a in tlist], dtype=float)
        return cls(col, r)
```

Use:

```
In [14]: tom = TomatoArr([['red', 'green'], ['green', 'red']], [[1.0, 1.2], [0.9, 1.1]])

In [15]: tom.col
Out[15]: 
array([['red', 'green'],
       ['green', 'red']], dtype='<U5')

In [16]: tom[:, 1].r
Out[16]: array([1.2, 1.1])

In [17]: tom[:, 0].r += 100

In [18]: tom.r
Out[18]: 
array([[101. ,   1.2],
       [100.9,   1.1]])

In [19]: tom2 = TomatoArr.from_list([TomatoArr('red', 1.3), TomatoArr('red', 1.4)])

In [20]: tom2.r
Out[20]: array([1.3, 1.4])

In [21]: tom2.col
Out[21]: array(['red', 'red'], dtype='<U5')
```

Of course, other numpy operations don't work and would make sense anyway - what is the sum of `'red'` and `'green'`?

Note: what won't work is assignment with boolean indexing:

```
# no effect
tom[tom.col=='red'].r = 10
```

You could add a method `__setitem__`, but that would only work for something like

```
tom[tom.col=='red'] = TomatoArr('red', 10)
```